# return being called twice in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I'm trying to implement a very basic login screen in my iOS app with username and password textfields.

I looked up how to have the view automatically focus on the passsword textfield after the user taps "next" upon entering a username.  However, for some reason, it appears that the return is being detected twice after the user enters their username.  Instead of keeping the keyboard on screen and focusing on the password textField, the keyboard disappears and neither textField is in focus.

What am I doing wrong?

**LoginViewController.m:**

```
@implementation LoginViewController


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        username = [[NSString alloc]init];
        keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc]initWithIdentifier:@"Login" accessGroup:nil];    
    }

    // Check if user presses next from the username textfield -> automatically go to password
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
        if (theTextField == self.txtPassword) {
            // try logging in
            NSLog(@"trying to proceed to submit form");

        } else if (theTextField == self.txtUsername) {
            // automatically go to the password field
            NSLog(@"trying to proceed to password field");
            [self.txtPassword becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

When I look at my logs, the following two logs appear after the user clicks "next" from the username field

```
2014-08-27 00:11:48.594 BiP[3049:60b] trying to proceed to password field
2014-08-27 00:11:48.640 BiP[3049:60b] trying to proceed to submit form
```

Comment: did u write anything in the method `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:`?

Comment: And u also need to check whther ur mouse is working properly, I had a same type of issue, that my mouse's single click gave double click on simulator.

Comment: You should probably be returning NO unless you want the return key character in your login/password.

Comment: @nazik I don't have this method implemented. I'm also testing on a physical device, not using my mouse.

Comment: @CrimsonChris WOW changing it to return NO did the trick!

Comment: @scientiffic That's because when you return YES it sends the return key to the field that has just become the first responder, which calls textFieldShouldReturn again on the next field.

Comment: @scientiffic You should consider putting resignFirstResponder in the submit part. This will dismiss the keyboard when the user gets to the end of your workflow.

Comment: got it, thanks for the help!  confusing to me that other examples always have the return set to YES.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
        if (theTextField == self.txtPassword) {
            // try logging in
            NSLog(@"trying to proceed to submit form");
            return YES;

        } else if (theTextField == self.txtUsername) {
            // automatically go to the password field
            NSLog(@"trying to proceed to password field");
            [self.txtPassword becomeFirstResponder];
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

Hope this helps.. :)